# how do I optimize this code to extract title

Tags: php

below is a sample code which I used to extract title of any website:

```
function fread_url($url,$ref="")
    {
        if(function_exists("curl_init")){
            $ch = curl_init();
            $user_agent = "googlebot";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
            $html = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
        else{
            $html.= file_get_contents($urweb);
               }
        return $html;
    }
////////////////////////////////////
$doc = new DOMDocument(); @$doc->loadHTML(@fread_url($urweb));  
$titlelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title"); 
if($titlelist->length > 0){   $wbtitle = $titlelist->item(0)->nodeValue; } 
echo $wbtitle;
```

My question is how can I modify this script to access a website for 5 seconds time and if no title available then return ampty?? right now for some websites it take morethan 5 seconds to extract title or even take more.

Comment: `$user_agent = "googlebot";` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a timeout for cURL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
```

It looks like you're trying to do that already with `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`, but that's

> The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect

whereas `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` timeout is

> The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the function entirely as follows. You could also make another function if you need to keep the fread_url() function.

```
function get_page_title($url, $ref = "") {
    if (function_exists("curl_init")) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $user_agent = "googlebot";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    } else {
        $html = file_get_contents($urweb);
    }

    if ($html === false || empty($html))
        return false;

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);  
    $titlelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title"); 

    return $titlelist->length > 0 ? $titlelist->item(0)->nodeValue : '';
}

$wbtitle = get_page_title($urlweb);
```

Comment: A good effort, thanks. But `$html .=` should be `$html = ` and `if ($html === false || empty($html) )` should be: `if (!$html) return FALSE;` You should also stick a default value for $html at the beginning of the function `$html = FALSE`.... oh and you should use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.

Comment: @SkippyChalmers Actually, `$html` will always be set, so it should shouldnt be that. it should be at least `if(empty($html)) return false;`

Comment: No. Absolutely not re. empty(). However yes, $html would always be set if it wasn't using a concatenation assignment '.=' (or whatever). Yes I know it still sets it anyway, but you're doing it wrong. Anyway, empty() essentially checks for falsey values, or at least anything in the $html variable that is considered falsey is of no use to the OP and should be considered as a failure.

Comment: if curl or the file_get_contents returns nothing, empty will throw false, why is that wrong? and html is set with or without the `.=`, i dont see why this is wrong, no offence, but i think you're throwing opinion into this

Comment: I think you're rushing in and not even answering his question :) I also think you can't take a little advice! When you define a variable, use '=' not '.=' - period! Why waste function overhead when you can just evaluate to falsey?

Comment: the .= was a typo. Sheesh, get over yourself. Explain this: if ($html === false || empty($html) ) should be: if (!$html) return FALSE;. My solution works just fine, and validates on two levels.

Comment: Actually your solution doesn't work at all. You need to add in the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT option. Don't hold onto clunky code for pride's sake. You're saying "check if HTML is equal to false, and then run it through a function to see if it's falsey, which could be a value like 0.0, FALSE, 0, NULL, etc)." I'm saying, "check if it's falsey". Which do you think is better practice?

Comment: @SkippyChalmers Doesnt work at all? with or without the timeout function, the code will work, just not completely answering the OP's question. and his method is more robust, so id say his.

Comment: @Ascherer we're arguing semantics here. What I said from the beginning about this answer still stands. The '.=' bug has been fixed, and the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` mistake has been acknowledged. All that remains is my suggestion to use `!$html` instead of `$html === FALSE || empty($html)`. Please, both of you, stop and think here for a minute. Think what empty does, think what !== false does and then add them both together, and tell me exactly why you think that @dtbarne's method is more robust???? Has the penny dropped yet? Yeah? Now kick yourselves.